# Saraswati Sooktam (Rigveda Samhitaa)

Tags: rig-veda, saraswati

Good day,
I am searching a good translation of the Saraswati Sooktam as per title,  in English.

Anyone has a good referral website ?

As suggested , i copy here the text of this Suktam i found.

[Saraswati Suktam by Challekere Brothers](https://youtu.be/0baDIsyG6qY)

> saraswatee sooktam 
>   (rigveda samhitaa)
>
> om iyamadadaadrabhasamruNachyutam divodaasam vadhryashvaaya daashushe | yaa shashvan tamaachakhashadaavasam paNim taa te daatraaNi tavishaa saraswatee
>   || 1 ||
>
> iyam shushmebhirbisakhaa ivaarujatsaanu gireeNaaMm tavishebhiroormibhihi | paaraavataghneemavase suvruktibhih saraswatee maa vivaasemadheetibhihi || 2 ||
>
> saraswati devanido ni barhaya prajaam vishvasya brusayasya maayinaha | uta kshitibhyo~vaneeravindo vishamebhyo asravo vaajineevati || 3 ||
>
> praNo devee saraswatee vaajebhirvaajineevatee | dheenaamavitryavatu || 4 ||
>
> yastvaa devi sarasvatyupabroote dhane hite | indram na vrutratoorye || 5 ||
>
> tvam devi sarasvatyavaa vaajeshu vaajini | radaa poosheva nah sanim || 6 ||
>
> uta syaa nah sarasvatee ghoraa hiraNyavartinihi | vrutraghnee vashTi sushTutim || 7 ||
>
> yasyaa ananto ahrutastveshashcharishNurarNavaha | amashcharati roruvat || 8 ||
>
> saa no vishvaa ati dvishah svasruranyaa rutaavaree | atannaheva sooryaha || 9 ||
>
> uta nah priyaa priyaasu saptasvasaa sujushTaa | sarasvatee stomyaa bhoot || 10 ||
>
> aapaprushee paarthivaanyuru rajo antariksham | sarasvatee nidaspaatu || 11 ||
>
> trishadhasthaa saptadhaatuh pancha jaataa vardhayantee | vaajevaaje havyaabhoota || 12 ||
>
> pra yaa mahimnaa mahinaasu chekite dyumnebhiranyaa apasaamapastamaa | ratha iva bruhatee vibhvane krutopastutyaa chikitushaa saraswatee || 13 ||
>
> sarasvatyabhi no neshi vasyo maapa sphareeh payasaa maa na aa dhak | jushasva nah sakhyaa veshyaa cha maa tvat kshetraaNyaraNaani ganma || 14 ||
>
> pra kshodasaa dhaayasaa sasra eshaa saraswatee dharuNamaayasee poohu | prabaabadhaanaa rathyeva yaati vishvaa apo mahinaa sindhuranyaaha || 15 ||
>
> ekaachetat saraswatee nadeenaam shuchiryatee giribhya aa samudraat | raayashchetantee bhuvanasya bhoorerghrutam payo duduhe naahushaaya || 16 ||
>
> sa vaavrudhe naryo yoshaNaasu vrushaa shishurvrushabho yagyiyaasu | sa vaajinam maghavadbhyo dadhaati vi saataye tanvam maamrujeeta || 17 ||
>
> uta syaa nah sarasvatee jushaaNopa shravat subhagaa yagye asmin | mitaj~jubhirnamasyairiyaanaa raayaa yujaa chiduttaraa sakhibhyaha || 18 ||
>
> imaa juhvaanaa yupmadaa namobhih prati stomam sarasvatee jushasva | tava sharman priyatame dadhaanaa upa stheyaama sharaNam na vruksham || 19 ||
>
> ayamu te sarasvati vasishTho dvaaraavrutasya subhage vyaavaha | vardha shubhre stuvate raasi vaajaan , yooyam paata svastibhih sadaa naha || 20 ||
>
> bruhadu gaayishe vacho~suryaa nadeenaam | sarasvateeminmahayaa suvruktibhih stomair vasishTha rodasee || 21 ||
>
> ubhe yatte mahinaa shubhre andhasee adhikshiyanti pooravaha | saa no bodhyavitree marutsakhaa choda raadho maghonaam || 22 ||
>
> bhadramid bhadraa kruNavat sarasvatyakavaaree chetati vaajineevatee | gruNaanaa jamadagnivat stuvaanaa cha vasishThavat || 23 ||
>
> janeeyanto nvagravah putreeyantah sudaanavaha | sarasvahantam havaamahe || 24 ||
>
> ye te sarasva oormayo madhumanto ghrutashchutaha | tebhirno~vitaa bhava || 25 ||
>
> peepivaamsam sarasvatah stanam yo vishvadarshataha | bhaksheemahi prajaamisham || 26 ||
>
> ambitame nadeetame devitame sarasvati | aprashastaa iva smasi prashastimamba naskrudhi || 27 ||
>
> tve vishvaa sarasvati shchitaayoomshi devyaam | shunahotreshu matsva prajaam devi didiDDhi naha || 28 ||
>
> imaa brahma sarasvati jushasva vaajineevati | yaa te manma grutsamadaa rutaavari priyaa deveshu juhvati || 29 ||
>
> paavakaa nah sarasvatee vaajebhirvaajineevatee | yagyam vashTu dhiyaavasuhu || 30 ||
>
> chodayitree soonrutaanaam chetantee sumateenaam | yagyam dadhe saraswatee || 31 ||
>
> maho arNah saraswatee pra chetayati ketunaa | dhiyo vishvaa vi raajati || 32 ||
>
> saraswateem devayanto havante saraswateemadhvare taayamaane | saraswateem sukruto ahvayanta sarasvatee daashushe vaaryamdaat || 33 ||
>
> sarasvati yaa saratham yayaatha svadhaabhirdevi pitrubhirmadantee || aasadyaasmin barhishi maadayasvaanameevaa isha aa dhehyasme || 34 ||
>
> saraswateem yaam pitaro havante dakshiNaa yagyamabhinakshamaaNaaha | sahasraarghamiLo atra bhaagam raayasposham yajamaaneshu dhehi || 35 ||
>
> aa no divo bruhatah parvataadaa sarasvatee yajataa gantu yagyam | havam devee jujushaaNaa ghrutaachee shagmaam no vaachamushatee shruNotu || 36 ||
>
> raakaamaham suhavaam sushTutee huve shruNotu nah subhagaa bodhatu tmanaa | seevyatvapah soochyaachChidyamaanayaa dadaatu veeram shatadaayamukthyam || 37 ||
>
> yaaste raake sumatayah supeshaso yaabhirdadaasi daashushe vasooni | taabhirno adya sumanaa upaagahi sahasraposham subhage raraaNaa || 38 ||
>
> sineevaali pruthushTuke yaa devaanaamasi svasaa | jushasva havyamaahutam prajaam devi didiDDhi naha || 39 ||
>
> yaa subaahuh svangurih sushoomaa bahusoovaree | tasyai vishpatnyai havih sineevaalyai juhotana || 40 ||
>
> yaa gungooryaa sineevaalee yaa raakaa yaa saraswatee | indraaNeemahva ootaye varuNaaneem svastaye || 41 ||
>
> om shaantih shaantih shaantihi |

Thank You in Advance

Kind Regards

Comment: When you are asking for a good referral website, the answers will be opinion based and your question may be closed.  Better change the question, asking for word to word meaning of Saraswati Suktam (RV 6.61), etc

Comment: Did it , Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see below, all of the mantras in your question (and [the YouTube video](https://youtu.be/0baDIsyG6qY) you linked) are sourced from the [Ṛgveda](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/1_veda/1_sam/1_rv/rvh1-10u.htm). I included the English translations for these from the [Oxford translation of Ṛgveda](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgzVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=twopage&q&f=false) by Stephanie Jamison and Joel Brereton.

You can find alternative translation of these verses on [this](http://universityofhumanunity.org/wp/archives/bibliodetail/?biblioid=2376) website (Sarasvati in the Veda - Part 1 thru 4) but they are not in the same order as your question or the video.

> RV_6,061.01a  iyam adadād rabhasam ṛṇacyutaṃ divodāsaṃ vadhryaśvāya dāśuṣe | 
>   RV_6,061.01c  yā śaśvantam ācakhādāvasam paṇiṃ tā te dātrāṇi taviṣā sarasvati || 
>   RV_6,061.02a  iyaṃ śuṣmebhir bisakhā ivārujat sānu girīṇāṃ taviṣebhir ūrmibhiḥ | 
>   RV_6,061.02c  pārāvataghnīm avase suvṛktibhiḥ sarasvatīm ā vivāsema dhītibhiḥ || 
>   RV_6,061.03a  sarasvati devanido ni barhaya prajāṃ viśvasya bṛsayasya māyinaḥ | 
>   RV_6,061.03c  uta kṣitibhyo 'vanīr avindo viṣam ebhyo asravo vājinīvati || 
>   RV_6,061.04a  pra ṇo devī sarasvatī vājebhir vājinīvatī | 
>   RV_6,061.04c  dhīnām avitry avatu || 
>   RV_6,061.05a  yas tvā devi sarasvaty upabrūte dhane hite | 
>   RV_6,061.05c  indraṃ na vṛtratūrye || 
>   RV_6,061.06a  tvaṃ devi sarasvaty avā vājeṣu vājini | 
>   RV_6,061.06c  radā pūṣeva naḥ sanim || 
>   RV_6,061.07a  uta syā naḥ sarasvatī ghorā hiraṇyavartaniḥ | 
>   RV_6,061.07c  vṛtraghnī vaṣṭi suṣṭutim || 
>   RV_6,061.08a  yasyā ananto ahrutas tveṣaś cariṣṇur arṇavaḥ | 
>   RV_6,061.08c  amaś carati roruvat || 
>   RV_6,061.09a  sā no viśvā ati dviṣaḥ svasṝr anyā ṛtāvarī | 
>   RV_6,061.09c  atann aheva sūryaḥ || 
>   RV_6,061.10a  uta naḥ priyā priyāsu saptasvasā sujuṣṭā | 
>   RV_6,061.10c  sarasvatī stomyā bhūt || 
>   RV_6,061.11a  āpapruṣī pārthivāny uru rajo antarikṣam | 
>   RV_6,061.11c  sarasvatī nidas pātu || 
>   RV_6,061.12a  triṣadhasthā saptadhātuḥ pañca jātā vardhayantī | 
>   RV_6,061.12c  vāje-vāje havyā bhūt || 
>   RV_6,061.13a  pra yā mahimnā mahināsu cekite dyumnebhir anyā apasām apastamā | 
>   RV_6,061.13c  ratha iva bṛhatī vibhvane kṛtopastutyā cikituṣā sarasvatī || 
>   RV_6,061.14a  sarasvaty abhi no neṣi vasyo māpa spharīḥ payasā mā na ā dhak | 
>   RV_6,061.14c  juṣasva naḥ sakhyā veśyā ca mā tvat kṣetrāṇy araṇāni ganma ||
>
> 1. She gave to the pious Vadhryaśva tempestuous Divodāsa who shakes the debtor, she who has wrenched away the provender from one niggard after another. These are your powerful gifts, o Sarasvatī.
> 2. She, like a root-grubbing (boar) with her snortings, broke the back of the mountains with her powerful waves. Sarasvatī, who smashes the foreigners, we would entice here for help with well-plaited (hymns), with visionary thoughts.
> 3. Sarasvatī, tear down the scorners of the gods, the offspring of every tricky Br̥saya. And (while) you found streambeds for the settlements, you flowed poison for them, o you rich in prize mares.
> 4. Let goddess Sarasvatī, rich in prize mares, with her prizes help us—the helper of visionary thoughts.
> 5. Whoever makes appeal to you, goddess Sarasvatī, when the stake is set, as if to Indra at the overcoming of Vr̥tra,
> 6. Aid (him), goddess Sarasvatī, at the prize (contests), you prizewinner. Channel gain to us, like Pūṣan.
> 7. And this Sarasvatī, having a golden course, fearsome, obstacle-smashing, wants our good praise—
> 8. Whose boundless, unswerving, turbulent, roving flood, her onslaught, proceeds ever roaring.
> 9. Beyond all hatreds, beyond her other sisters [=rivers] has the truthful one extended us, like the sun the days.
> 10. And she, dear(est) among the dear (rivers), having seven sisters, very delightful—Sarasvatī is (ever) worthy of our praise.
> 11. Having filled the earthly (places), the broad realm, the midspace, let Sarasvatī protect (us) from scorn.
> 12. Having three seats and seven parts, strengthening the five peoples, at every prize contest she is worthy to be invoked.
> 13. The one who by her greatness shines ever more brightly among the great (rivers), (beyond) the others by her brilliance, the busiest of the busy, like a chariot lofty and fashioned for wide ranging, she is to be praised by (every) observant one—Sarasvatī.
> 14. O Sarasvatī, lead us to a better state. Do not spring away with your milk; do not come up short for us. Take delight in our partnerships and communities. Let us not go from you to alien dwelling places.

---

> RV_7,095.01a  pra kṣodasā dhāyasā sasra eṣā sarasvatī dharuṇam āyasī pūḥ |         
>   RV_7,095.01c  prabābadhānā rathyeva yāti viśvā apo mahinā sindhur anyāḥ ||         
>   RV_7,095.02a  ekācetat sarasvatī nadīnāṃ śucir yatī giribhya ā samudrāt |          
>   RV_7,095.02c  rāyaś cetantī bhuvanasya bhūrer ghṛtam payo duduhe nāhuṣāya ||       
>   RV_7,095.03a  sa vāvṛdhe naryo yoṣaṇāsu vṛṣā śiśur vṛṣabho yajñiyāsu |             
>   RV_7,095.03c  sa vājinam maghavadbhyo dadhāti vi sātaye tanvam māmṛjīta ||         
>   RV_7,095.04a  uta syā naḥ sarasvatī juṣāṇopa śravat subhagā yajṇe asmin |          
>   RV_7,095.04c  mitajñubhir namasyair iyānā rāyā yujā cid uttarā sakhibhyaḥ ||       
>   RV_7,095.05a  imā juhvānā yuṣmad ā namobhiḥ prati stomaṃ sarasvati juṣasva |       
>   RV_7,095.05c  tava śarman priyatame dadhānā upa stheyāma śaraṇaṃ na vṛkṣam ||      
>   RV_7,095.06a  ayam u te sarasvati vasiṣṭho dvārāv ṛtasya subhage vy āvaḥ |         
>   RV_7,095.06c  vardha śubhre stuvate rāsi vājān yūyam pāta svastibhiḥ sadā naḥ ||
>
> 1. She has flowed forth with her surge, with her nourishment—Sarasvatī is a buttress, a metal fortress. Thrusting forward all the other waters with her greatness, the river drives like a lady-charioteer.
> 2. Alone of the rivers, Sarasvatī shows clear, as she goes gleaming from the mountains all the way to the sea. Taking note of the abundant wealth of the world, she has milked out ghee and milk for the Nāhuṣa.
> 3. He has grown strong as a manly one among maidens, a bullish bull calf among the (river-maidens) worthy of the sacrifice. He provides a prizewinner to the benefactors. He should groom his body for winning.
> 4. And this Sarasvatī, the well-portioned, will harken to this sacrifice of ours, taking pleasure in it, being implored by reverential ones with their knees fixed. With wealth as her yokemate, she is even higher than her companions.
> 5. Here are (oblations) being poured all the way to you (rivers), along with reverences. Take pleasure in the praise, Sarasvatī. Being set in your dearest shelter, may we stand nearby it like a sheltering tree.
> 6. And this Vasiṣṭha here has opened up the doors of truth for you, well-portioned Sarasvatī. Strengthen (him?), resplendent one; grant prizes to the praiser. – Do you protect us always with your blessings.

---

> RV_7,096.01a  bṛhad u gāyiṣe vaco 'suryā nadīnām |                                 
>   RV_7,096.01c  sarasvatīm in mahayā suvṛktibhi stomair vasiṣṭha rodasī ||           
>   RV_7,096.02a  ubhe yat te mahinā śubhre andhasī adhikṣiyanti pūravaḥ |             
>   RV_7,096.02c  sā no bodhy avitrī marutsakhā coda rādho maghonām ||                 
>   RV_7,096.03a  bhadram id bhadrā kṛṇavat sarasvaty akavārī cetati vājinīvatī |      
>   RV_7,096.03c  gṛṇānā jamadagnivat stuvānā ca vasiṣṭhavat ||                        
>   RV_7,096.04a  janīyanto nv agravaḥ putrīyantaḥ sudānavaḥ |                         
>   RV_7,096.04c  sarasvantaṃ havāmahe ||                                              
>   RV_7,096.05a  ye te sarasva ūrmayo madhumanto ghṛtaścutaḥ |                        
>   RV_7,096.05c  tebhir no 'vitā bhava ||                                             
>   RV_7,096.06a  pīpivāṃsaṃ sarasvata stanaṃ yo viśvadarśataḥ |                       
>   RV_7,096.06c  bhakṣīmahi prajām iṣam ||
>
> 1. I shall sing a lofty speech: she is the lordly one of the rivers. Magnify Sarasvatī with well-twisted (hymns); with praises (magnify) the two world-halves, o Vasiṣṭha.
> 2. Since by your might, resplendent lady, the Pūrus preside over both "stalks" [=honey and ghee? soma and surā? two banks of river?], become our helper, with the Maruts as companions. Stimulate the generosity of the benefactors.
> 3. Good Sarasvatī will do good. She shows brightly as the unstinting one, rich in prize mares, while she is being hymned as she was by Jamadagni and she is being praised as she was by Vasiṣṭha.
> 4. As bachelors in search of wives, in search of sons, possessing lovely gifts, we call upon Sarasvant.
> 5. Your waves, Sarasvant, which are rich in honey, dripping with ghee—with them become our helper.
> 6. The swelling breast of Sarasvant, which is lovely for all to see—we would share (in it and) in offspring and refreshment.

---

> RV_2,041.16a  ambitame nadītame devitame sarasvati |                   
>   RV_2,041.16c  apraśastā iva smasi praśastim amba nas kṛdhi ||          
>   RV_2,041.17a  tve viśvā sarasvati śritāyūṃṣi devyām |                  
>   RV_2,041.17c  śunahotreṣu matsva prajāṃ devi didiḍḍhi naḥ ||           
>   RV_2,041.18a  imā brahma sarasvati juṣasva vājinīvati |                
>   RV_2,041.18c  yā te manma gṛtsamadā ṛtāvari priyā deveṣu juhvati ||
>
> 16. O best mother, best river, best goddess, Sarasvatī—we are like ones unlauded: make a laud for us, mother.
> 17. In you, the goddess, are all lifetimes fixed, o Sarasvatī. Become exhilarated among the Śunahotras. Allot offspring to us, goddess.
> 18. Enjoy these sacred formulations here, o Sarasvatī rich in prize-winning mares, the thoughts dear to the gods that the Gr̥tsamadas pour for you, truthful one.

---

> RV_1,003.10a  pāvakā naḥ sarasvatī vājebhir vājinīvatī |       
>   RV_1,003.10c  yajñaṃ vaṣṭu dhiyāvasuḥ ||                       
>   RV_1,003.11a  codayitrī sūnṛtānāṃ cetantī sumatīnām |          
>   RV_1,003.11c  yajñaṃ dadhe sarasvatī ||                        
>   RV_1,003.12a  maho arṇaḥ sarasvatī pra cetayati ketunā |       
>   RV_1,003.12c  dhiyo viśvā vi rājati ||
>
> 10. Let pure Sarasvatī, providing prize mares along with prizes, be eager for our sacrifice, bringing goods through her insight.
> 11. The impeller of liberal gifts, taking note of good thoughts, Sarasvatī has received our sacrifice.
> 12. Her great flood does Sarasvatī reveal with her beacon. She rules over all insights.

---

> RV_10,017.07a  sarasvatīṃ devayanto havante sarasvatīm adhvare tāyamāne |          
>   RV_10,017.07c  sarasvatīṃ sukṛto ahvayanta sarasvatī dāśuṣe vāryaṃ dāt ||          
>   RV_10,017.08a  sarasvati yā sarathaṃ yayātha svadhābhir devi pitṛbhir madantī |    
>   RV_10,017.08c  āsadyāsmin barhiṣi mādayasvānamīvā iṣa ā dhehy asme ||              
>   RV_10,017.09a  sarasvatīṃ yām pitaro havante dakṣiṇā yajñam abhinakṣamāṇāḥ |       
>   RV_10,017.09c  sahasrārgham iḷo atra bhāgaṃ rāyas poṣaṃ yajamāneṣu dhehi ||
>
> 7. Sarasvatī do those seeking the gods invoke, Sarasvatī when the ceremony is being extended. Sarasvatī did those of good action invoke. Sarasvatī will give a thing of value to the pious.
> 8. O Sarasvatī, you who drove on the same chariot with the forefathers, becoming exhilarated at the svadhā(-calls), o goddess—having taken your seat here on this ritual grass, bring yourself to exhilaration. Provide us refreshments that bring no disease.
> 9. Sarasvatī, whom the forefathers invoke, as they arrive at the sacrifice in the south—provide here a portion of refreshment worth thousands and thriving of wealth among the sacrificers.

---

> RV_5,043.11a  ā no divo bṛhataḥ parvatād ā sarasvatī yajatā gantu yajñam | 
>   RV_5,043.11c  havaṃ devī jujuṣāṇā ghṛtācī śagmāṃ no vācam uśatī śṛṇotu ||
>
> 11. Hither to us from lofty heaven, from the mountain let Sarasvatī, deserving the sacrifice, come to the sacrifice. Let the goddess, having enjoyed our call, turning toward the ghee, listen willingly to our capable speech.

---

> RV_2,032.04a  rākām ahaṃ suhavāṃ suṣṭutī huve śṛṇotu naḥ subhagā bodhatu tmanā |   
>   RV_2,032.04c  sīvyatv apaḥ sūcyācchidyamānayā dadātu vīraṃ śatadāyam ukthyam ||    
>   RV_2,032.05a  yās te rāke sumatayaḥ supeśaso yābhir dadāsi dāśuṣe vasūni |         
>   RV_2,032.05c  tābhir no adya sumanā upāgahi sahasrapoṣaṃ subhage rarāṇā ||         
>   RV_2,032.06a  sinīvāli pṛthuṣṭuke yā devānām asi svasā |                           
>   RV_2,032.06c  juṣasva havyam āhutam prajāṃ devi didiḍḍhi naḥ ||                    
>   RV_2,032.07a  yā subāhuḥ svaṅguriḥ suṣūmā bahusūvarī |                             
>   RV_2,032.07c  tasyai viśpatnyai haviḥ sinīvālyai juhotana ||                       
>   RV_2,032.08a  yā guṅgūr yā sinīvālī yā rākā yā sarasvatī |                         
>   RV_2,032.08c  indrāṇīm ahva ūtaye varuṇānīṃ svastaye ||
>
> 4. Rākā who is good to invoke I invoke with good praise. Let her of good portion hear us; let her attend (to us) in person. Let her stitch her work with a needle that cannot be broken. Let her give a hero with a hundred shares who is worthy of hymns.
> 5. O Rākā, your benevolent thoughts, well-ornamented, with which you give goods to the pious one—with those approach us today, benevolently, granting thousandfold thriving, you of good portion.
> 6. O Sinīvalī with broad braids, you who are sister of the gods, enjoy the oblation that is poured. Allot offspring to us, goddess.
> 7. She who has lovely arms, lovely fingers, bearing easily, bearing amply, to her, mistress of the clan, to Sinīvalī, pour an oblation.
> 8. Guṅgū, Sinīvalī, Rākā, Sarasvatī—(on them and) on Indrāṇī I have called for help and on Varuṇānī for well-being.

Comment: excellent, thank you! also i used from time to time the Ralph T.H. Griffith translation which i honestly don’t really like at all, even better the transliteration of Aurobindo , but it is incomplete. I will have a look at the texts you provided , in the meanwhile here are the 100 points as offered.

Answer (score 1):

Translation in [Green message](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_mantras.php)

> पावका नः सरस्वती वाजेभिर्वाजिनीवती । 
>   यज्ञं वष्टु धियावसुः ॥१.३.१०॥
>
> Paavakaa Nah Sarasvatii Vaajebhir-Vaajiniivatii | 
>   Yajnyam Vassttu Dhiyaavasuh ||1.3.10||
>
> Meaning:
>   1: O Saraswati, You are the purifier (of our Intellect), and Your Strength (of Wisdom) grows within us with Sacrificial Offerings (inner and outer),
>   2: May my offering in Yagnya strengthen Your Wisdom within me (i.e. May Your presence within me make me rich in Wisdom).
>
> चोदयित्री सूनृतानां चेतन्ती सुमतीनाम् । 
>   यज्ञं दधे सरस्वती ॥१.३.११॥
>   Codayitrii Suunrtaanaam Cetantii Sumatiinaam | 
>   Yajnyam Dadhe Sarasvatii ||1.3.11||
>
> Meaning:
>   1: (Saraswati Who) Inspires us towards Truth and awakens our Goodness (Sumati),
>   2: (That Saraswati) has (now) held this Yagnya (i.e. Has accepted my offerings).
>
> महो अर्णः सरस्वती प्र चेतयति केतुना । 
>   धियो विश्वा वि राजति ॥१.३.१२॥
>   Maho Arnnah Sarasvatii Pra Cetayati Ketunaa | 
>   Dhiyo Vishvaa Vi Raajati ||1.3.12||
>
> Meaning:
>   1: Saraswati, that Great Wave (of Universal Wisdom) (Who has flowed as a River) and Who is the awakener of our Intellect, ...
>   2: ... is (now) shining as the embodiment of Universal Wisdom (in this Yagnya).

Next from [Puja net](http://www.puja.net/wordpress/saraswati-suktam/)

> Paavakaa na Saraswathi
>   Vajebhi vajnivathi
>   Yagnam vasthu dhiyaavasu.
>
> Saraswathi is the purifier,
>   Giver of plenty and opulent life,
>   Who is rich in thought and intelligence.
>
> Chodayathri soonruthaanaam,
>   Chethanthi sumathinaam,
>   Yajnam dadhe Saraswathi.
>
> She blesses one with good speech,
>   She brings good thoughts to mind,
>   And let her bless this Yagna (sacrifice).
>
> Maho arnaah Saraswathi,
>   Prachethayathi kethunaa,
>   Dhiyo vishva virajethi.
>
> Oh Saraswathi, please awaken the truth in me,
>   By helping me to perceive the consciousness,
>   And illuminate my entire thought.
>
> Prano devi saraswathi,
>   Vajhebhir vajinavathi,
>   Dhinam avithri avathu.
>
> Oh Saraswathi, be pleased,
>   To give me a plenty and opulent life,
>   And become the protector of our thoughts.

Another Saraswati Sukta is from Rigveda 6:LXI. Below is the translation of [Griffith](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm).

> 1. To Vadhryasva when. be worshipped her with gifts she gave fierce Divodāsa, canceller of debts.
>      Consumer of the churlish niggard, one and all, thine, O Sarasvatī, are these effectual boons.
>      2 She with her might, like one who digs for lotus-stems, hath burst with her strong waves the ridges of the hills.
>      Let us invite with songs and holy hymns for help Sarasvatī who slayeth the Paravatas.
>      3 Thou castest down, Sarasvatī, those who scorned the Gods, the brood of every Bṛsaya skilled in magic arts.
>      Thou hast discovered rivers for the tribes of men, and, rich in wealth! made poison flow away from them.
>      4 May the divine Sarasvatī, rich in her wealth, protect us well,
>      Furthering all our thoughts with might
>      5 Whoso, divine Sarasvatī, invokes thee where the prize is set,
>      Like Indra when he smites the foe.
>      6 Aid us, divine Sarasvad, thou who art strong in wealth and power
>      Like Pūṣan, give us opulence.
>      7 Yea, this divine Sarasvatī, terrible with her golden path,
>      Foe-slayer, claims our eulogy.
>      8 Whose limitless unbroken flood, swift-moving with a rapid rush,
>      Comes onward with tempestuous roar.
>      9 She hath spread us beyond all foes, beyond her Sisters, Holy One,
>      As Sūrya spreadeth out the days.
>      10 Yea, she most dear amid dear stream, Seven-sistered, graciously inclined,
>      Sarasvatī hath earned our praise.
>      11 Guard us from hate Sarasvatī, she who hath filled the realms of earth,
>      And that wide tract, the firmament!
>      12 Seven-sistered, sprung from threefold source, the Five Tribes' prosperer, she must be
>      Invoked in every deed of might.
>      13 Marked out by majesty among the Mighty Ones, in glory swifter than the other rapid Streams,
>      Created vast for victory like a chariot, Sarasvatī must be extolled by every sage.
>      14 Guide us, Sarasvatī, to glorious treasure: refuse us not thy milk, nor spurn us from thee.
>      Gladly accept our friendship and obedience: let us not go from thee to distant countries.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: The Puja.net translation is the same one I have given from Hindupedia.

Comment: https://youtu.be/0baDIsyG6qY